# Angular - Refresh component from other component : child to parent then parent to another child communication

Tags: angular

how can i refresh component from another component using `@Output` decorator?

in my case, i need to refresh **component C** from **component B** => on (click)="uploadMenu()

`Parent : component A
Child1 : component B
Child2 : component C`

**Component A** (parent)
`html`

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <app-uploadmenus></app-uploadmenus>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <app-listemenus></app-listemenus>
      </div>
</div>
```

**Component B** (child)
`html`

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="uploadMenu()">
```

**Component B** (child) 
`TS`<== action

```
uploadMenu() {

  this.appService.insertMenuSql(this.downloadurl, this.filename).subscribe((data) => {

      this.message = data["msessage"];

      //action here

    }, error => console.log(error));
  }
```

**Component C** (child) 
`TS`<== target to refresh

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

//???

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listemenus',
  templateUrl: './listemenus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listemenus.component.scss']
})
export class ListemenusComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `EventEmitter` in child B to execute a function in parent A, which then uses a `ViewChild` in A, to execute a function in child C.

easy peasy.

component A should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <app-uploadmenus (messageEvent)="uploadMenuPressed($event)"></app-uploadmenus>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <app-listemenus></app-listemenus>
  </div>
</div>
```

component B Needs these 3 things:

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

buttonPressed() {
  this.messageEvent.emit('done');
}
```

component C needs:

```
refreshMenu() {
  //do something here
}
```

finally component A needs a view child and a function to accept the emit call

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CComponent } from ...
@ViewChild(CComponent) cComponent: CComponent;

uploadMenuPressed(event:string) {
  this.cComponent.refreshMenu();
}
```

that should do it. good luck!

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH brother :D you are a genuis